# How to make a localized application?

Tags: windows-phone

I would like to make my app localized but I don't know where to start from. I gave a look to the msdn guide but I didn't really understood. My app would be localized for italian, french and english. Could someone help me?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of tutorials for this found with a quick web search. [Including Step-by-Step tutorials like this one](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Localizing-a-Windows-Phone-app-Step-by-Step). In the future you might include what you've tried or look into some other resources before asking such a broad question. If I remember right there's also step-by-step video tutorials available at the usual places.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway I had no code at all and if I asked such a question it was because what I had found wasn't clear enough.